# Exam class - Create two short tests on the same .tex file

Tags: exam

I want to compile a test on an A4 paper page. It's a short test (1 or 2 questions) so that i can put them one below the other to cut the paper test afterwards in two A5 pages.

I want to use `exam`class to produce my document but i can't find a way to set a new counter to count the total points of each part. At the moment, my `\numpoint` command count the two lists.

How can i create a new counter for my second total points and do not increment the previous one when adding a new exercise ?

EDIT : I've just noticed that the second `questions` list produce an issue for the `\totalpoints` command. The two exercises have the same value. I'll try to fix it too.

Here a MWE :

```
\documentclass[addpoints, 12pt, a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[top=1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}

%%Police
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}

%%Nom de l'interrogation
\newcommand{\theinterro}{1 A}
\newcommand{\thetitle}{Rappels de 3\up{ème}}


%%Format cote
\newlength{\pointslength}
\qformat{\settowidth{\pointslength}{\totalpoints}
    \textbf{Question \thequestion}\hfill \raisebox{0cm}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (points) at (0,0) [draw, rounded corners, minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=1cm] {\hspace{2\pointslength}/\totalpoints};
        \end{tikzpicture}} }

\pointsinmargin

%%  Retrait
\renewcommand{\subpartshook}{\addtolength{\leftmargin}{-0.6cm}}


\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.3}
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}|}
        \hline 
        Nom : & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{3cm}{\vspace{0.5cm} \centering Interrogation \theinterro\\ - \\ \thetitle\vspace{0.5cm}\\ {\hspace{2cm} /\numpoints}}}  & \multirow{2}{*}{  \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}} \\ 
        \cline{1-1}
        Prénom : &  &  \\ 
        \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3} 
        Classe : &  & Date : \\ 
        \hline 
    \end{tabular} 
    \end{center}

    \begin{questions}
        \question[3] One pretty difficult exercise.
    \end{questions}
    \vfill

%%Test B
\renewcommand{\theinterro}{1 B}
    \begin{center}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.3}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}|}
            \hline 
            Nom : & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{3cm}{\vspace{0.5cm} \centering Interrogation \theinterro\\ - \\ \thetitle\vspace{0.5cm}\\ {\hspace{2cm} /\numpoints}}}  & \multirow{2}{*}{  \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}} \\ 
            \cline{1-1}
            Prénom : &  &  \\ 
            \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3} 
            Classe : &  & Date : \\ 
            \hline 
        \end{tabular} 
    \end{center}

    \begin{questions}
        \question[2] One other pretty difficult exercise.
    \end{questions}
    \vfill
\end{document}
```

Output :
[image: Output]

Comment: Have you considered to use a5 paper for your exam, and use the possibilities of your printer driver to print two a5 pages on one a4 paper?

Comment: The format is not the problem. And for example, it's easier to produce two a4 pages to print two side-by-side. The issue i've to tackle is about the counters. At the moment, i can't solve the increments of the points for the two tests a part if they are on two differents `.tex` files.